# Standard SQL with ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-server

Is it possible to use Python to run actual standard SQL on an enterprise geo-database?
Think about batch deleting, joints, etc moving beyond just the cursor objects in Arcpy.

Note that one can shortcut ArcGIS and directly work with the back end database, but that is not the purpose of the questions here (and it I'd not recommended if you have n advanced geodatabase, like a versioned one)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, using [arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/ArcSDESQLExecute/018z0000007z000000/). You'll find various examples in the hyperlink.

Comment: Great! Yet, this only helps with not using another library for executing SQL but does not help with staying within ArcGIS constraints, i.e. dealing with versions. The same guide specifically mentions not to use this on any geo-database and/or versioned system.

Comment: Sure it's not perfect, but it helps in some cases. I didn't understand your question was specifically about versioned databases, sorry.

Comment: Not specifically, but the documentation reads as if, it is there, but you shouldn't really use it if you want to stay within the bounds of ArcGIS.